# Saving off a rect for future rendering in html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics

I am using an html5 canvas to draw many small objects. I have a loop that periodically updates the state of the objects and redraws them. Most of the objects will change very infrequently (kind of like a background), but right now I am looping through all of the objects at every iteration of the main loop. I would like to avoid this because as the number of objects gets large, the application freezes up.

My idea is to draw the relatively static objects once onto a background rect, and redraw this rect at every iteration rather than looping through each of the objects. The background image will only be updated if one of the infrequently changing objects changes.

I am not sure how to accomplish this using the canvas or if this is the best way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the "multiple canvas" approach, where a canvas is a "layer" (think of photoshop, or GIMP) and they are stacked on top of one another. When animating, you only need to redraw the canvases or "layers" that needed redraw. For example, of 10 layers you have, only 5, 7, 8 need redraw. You save yourself redrawing the rest (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9 and 10) since they are in isolated canvases. Therefore, in the entire scene, you only redraw 3 objects rather than all 10.

The [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) framework applies this concept, and it's pretty good at it. Its `Kinetic.Layer` class basically creates a canvas each, stacked on top of one another.